# ASP Classic "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: 'hashHelp'"

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Here I have a double Directory that is suppose to be carrying information from a database in the form of the object hashHelp. Clearly, this isn't working.
Based on everything I've found on this website and around the web, this error message seems to imply that the object hashHelp isn't being created, but you can clearly see it being created above. I have check  Any idea what could be happening?

```
    do until rs.eof
        if valid(cart, rs, data) = true then
                Dim hashHelp 
                Set hashHelp = new HashHelper
                hashHelp.setCode(rs.Fields("Code"))
                hashHelp.setDateTime(rs.Fields("ScanTime"))
                Dim entry
                entry = DateDiff("d", beginDate, DateValue(rs.Fields("ScanTime")))
                hash.Item(rs.Fields("ScanTime")).Item(arr(entry)) = hashHelp
                arr(DateDiff("d", beginDate, rs.Fields("ScanTime"))) = arr(DateDiff("d", beginDate, rs.Fields("ScanTime"))) + 1
        End If
        rs.movenext
    loop
    rs.close
```

The line the error happens on is                     hash.Item(rs.Fields("ScanTime")).Item(arr(entry)) = hashHelp
I've checked all the other variable and they are being created and used just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `hashHelp`'s DateTime rather that the object itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. hashHelp is a class I wrote whose only job is to store a Code and DateTime, and then be stored in the 2d dictionary as that I can access both when I look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: Try using the `Set` keyword: `Set hash.Item(rs.Fields("ScanTime")).Item(arr(entry)) = hashHelp`.

Comment: I think that got it, thanks!